# Is this XML valid?

Tags: xml

I have to write a script to transfer data to a web server, and the server receives data as XML and sends back responses in XML. In one particular case it's send me back the XML:

```
<operation name="ADD_REQUEST">
  <result>
    <status>Failed</status>
    <message>Error when performing - ADD_REQUEST - The element type "Details" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</Details>".</message>
  </result>
</operation>
```

This is crashing the MSXML.DOMDocument I'm using to parse it because of the:

```
"</Details>"
```

embedded in the message. If I manually edit this to

```
"&lt;/Details&gt;"
```

the XML parses fine.

my question is whether the MS parser is being excessively picky or whether the server is sending back invalid, i.e. improperly encoded, XML? If the latter, I'll bitch at the people who maintain the server (it's not something I have any control over myself).

Comment: It's not valid according to http://validator.w3.org

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp says the same

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just asking for a syntax check

Comment: This is fails within fails. The server complains about a non-well-formed message by responding...with a non-well-formed message? Nice work, server.

Comment: It's not even well-formed, and it can't be valid unless it is well-formed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not valid XML being returned. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) clearly says:

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not
>   appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters,
>   or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If
>   they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric
>   character references or the strings " `&amp;` " and " `&lt;` "
>   respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the
>   string " `&gt;` ", and must, for compatibility, be escaped using either
>   " `&gt;` " or a character reference when it appears in the string " ]]>
>   " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA
>   section.